# Texture Packer with Xcode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, texturepacker

I added texturePacker script to export sprite sheet and its working. I would like to know how to set 'Pre Multiply Alpha' and 'NPot any size' while exporting sheet through Xcode script?

Here is my present Code:

```
TP="/usr/local/bin/TexturePacker"

${TP} --smart-update \
--format cocos2d \
--padding 2 \
--main-extension "-ipadhd" \
--autosd-variant 0.5:-ipad \
--autosd-variant 0.5:-hd \
--autosd-variant 0.25: \
--opt RGBA8888 \
--data iOS/Resources/Game_SpriteSheet/CBirdSpriteSheet_1-ipadhd.plist \
--sheet iOS/Resources/Game_SpriteSheet/CBirdSpriteSheet_1-ipadhd.pvr.ccz \
SpriteSheet/Sprite_Sheet_1/*.png
```

Screenshot from external texture packer. I want same in script.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the `--premultiply-alpha` and `--size-constraints <value>` options to the command? [1]

```
TP="/usr/local/bin/TexturePacker"

${TP} --smart-update \
--format cocos2d \
--padding 2 \
--main-extension "-ipadhd" \
--autosd-variant 0.5:-ipad \
--autosd-variant 0.5:-hd \
--autosd-variant 0.25: \
--opt RGBA8888 \
--premultiply-alpha \
--size-constraints NPOT \
--data iOS/Resources/Game_SpriteSheet/CBirdSpriteSheet_1-ipadhd.plist \
--sheet iOS/Resources/Game_SpriteSheet/CBirdSpriteSheet_1-ipadhd.pvr.ccz \
SpriteSheet/Sprite_Sheet_1/*.png
```

[1] http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/documentation